# ¥ character transforms to \ after encoding/decoding in Shift-JIS

Tags: python, encoding

How is this possible? Is it a bug? (Same behavior in Python 2.7.12 and Python 3.5.1.)

```
In [1]: yen = u'\u00A5'

In [2]: print(yen)
¥

In [3]: yen_after_encoding_decoding = yen.encode('shift-jis').decode('shift-jis')

In [4]: print(yen_after_encoding_decoding)
\

In [5]: yen
Out[5]: '¥'

In [6]: yen_after_encoding_decoding
Out[6]: '\\'

In [7]:
```

The shift-jis encoding for yen is the same as the ASCII encoding for backslash, so presumably that's related. But still weird!

Comment: I remember there was exactly this code page confusion somewhere two decades ago, and Japanese Windows users use the ¥ sign instead of the backslash in paths because of it. Started as a bug, became a feature, too late to change now. Not sure if that's still the case in Windows 10…?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/33726867/5320906

Answer (score 0):

Character set of Shift_JIS is defined in JIS (Japanese Industrial Standard).
Character encoding Shift_JIS uses JIS X 0201 for half-width character set, and JIS X 0208 for full-width character set.

"backslash" in the question mean the half-width backslash in ISO/IEC 8859-1(Latin-1), and is represented as `0x005C`. On the other hand, JIS X 0201 (half-width character set) doesn't contain backslash (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JIS_X_0201). It uses yen sign instead of backslash in `0x005C`. Many Japanese applications (ex. Windows Explorer in Japanese locale) uses yen sign as equivalent of backslash like `C:¥Windows`.

In this situation, the behavior of the code looks like this:

- `yen` is `U+00A5` in Unicode.
- `yen.encode('shift-jis')` is `0x005C` in `bytes`, because `¥` is contained in Shift-JIS and is `0x005C` in its encoding.
- `.decode('shift-jis')` convert `0x005C` to `U+005C` (half-width backslash) in Unicode, because `¥` is used as equivalent of backslash.